# Undefined type 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I use the Maatwebsite package to import Excel files in Laravel 8. I also executed the following command after installing the package and adding needed aliases and providers in the app.php.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"
```

But when I create an import with a model Mymodel (a model that I have), I get the following error.

> undefined Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

**Import class**

```
class Importer implements ToModel
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Universite([
            //
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an error message. Providing the actual error message might get you faster assistance. You shouldn't touch app.php, it hasn't been needed for years now. Everything auto-registers after your run composer.

Answer (score 9):

You have to restart your VS Code, because it'll apply your latest package installed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32924581)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before you create the class:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
```